# Sumproduct in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sumproduct

Using dplyr, I´m trying to sumproduct in R two columns as it can be done in Excel but although I´ve tried several aproaches, none worked properly.

A small piece of my dataframe (almost 61000 rows and 20 columns) looks like this:

```
df <-structure(list(dem_sect = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("AB", 
"EP", "FE", "MF", "PA"), class = "factor"), cod_estr = c("a", 
"a", "b", "b", "c", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "c", "b", "b", "a", 
"b", "c", "c", "b", "c"), sect_estr = structure(c(10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("ABa", "ABb", "ABc", "EPa", "EPb", 
"EPc", "FEa", "FEb", "FEc", "MFa", "MFb", "MFc", "PAa", "PAb", 
"PAc"), class = "factor"), area = c(14L, 14L, 24L, 24L, 11L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 14L, 24L, 11L, 24L, 24L, 14L, 24L, 11L, 11L, 24L, 
11L), kg_med = c(5.88125, 5.88125, 6.8505, 6.8505, 
3.0852, 6.8505, 6.8505, 6.8505, 5.88125, 6.8505, 3.0852, 6.8505, 
6.8505, 5.88125, 6.8505, 3.0852, 3.0852, 6.8505, 3.0852)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

I want to add a new column (called for example *sumprod*) which would be the sumproduct of the **unique** values of both *"area"* and *"kg_med"* grouped by *"dem_sect"*

The expect output will be a column with the value `280.69` (If I did the calculation correctly in Excel)

Any help will be more than welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(dem_sect) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(area, kg_med)) %>% 
  summarise(sumproduct = sum(area * kg_med)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() # to view the result with more significant digits

#>   dem_sect sumproduct
#> 1       MF   280.6867
```

Comment: You don't seem to have handled OP's request to consider only *unique* values of the two columns.

Comment: You area right, @Limey! Thanks! I have misread the question...

Comment: Been there.  Done that.  Bought the t-shirt.  In many different sizes and colours.

Comment: Fixed that, meanwhile, @Limey!

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(dem_sect) %>% 
  distinct(area, kg_med) %>% 
  summarise(sumprod=sum(area*kg_med))
  dem_sect sumprod
  <fct>      <dbl>
1 MF          281.
```

This solution assumes that each value of `area` is associated with a single value of `kg_med` and vice-versa.  The desired behaviour with different numbers of unique values in each of the two columns is not well specified.

To check the accuracy of the answer to more than three significant digits...

```
old <- options(pillar.sigfig = 7)
df %>% 
  group_by(dem_sect) %>% 
  distinct(area, kg_med) %>% 
  summarise(sumprod=sum(area*kg_med))

# A tibble: 1 × 2
  dem_sect  sumprod
  <fct>       <dbl>
1 MF       280.6867

options(old)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! @Limey. You nailed the solution!!. I tried several approaches using unique and the trick was to use distinct. Everyday I learn something new about dplyr.

Comment: `unique` is a base R function, `distinct` is a dplyr function.  There are subtle differences in their behaviour, particularly when passed a data frame as their first argument.  If you have a satisfactory answer to your question, please accept either @PaulS' or mine to signpost to other users that you have the information you need.